# Mixin in Vue js(Not able to get updated value in component when i switch between component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using global mixin in vue js but the problem is my component is not getting updated value when i switch between component while i am returning value from method(I am able to get it when i toggle state(offline/online) when in same component again). I want to update value of "checkOnline" based on network detection without refreshing the browser, which works fine but if i navigate to other tab and their i disconnect from network and comeback to previous tab the state of "checkOnline" is not updated.

x.js

```
import {bus} from '../main';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checkOnline: navigator.onLine || false
    }
  },
  created() {
    bus.$on('detected-condition', this.disableButton)
  },
  watch: {
    checkOnline: function (val) {
        if (navigator.onLine) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    disableButton($event) {
      if ($event) {
        this.checkOnline = false
      } else {
        this.checkOnline = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

a.vue

```
<v-flex xs12 class="text-xs-center">
       <v-btn fab dark small :color="checkOnline ? 'grey' : 'primary'" class="mx-0 mb-0 elevation-4" :class="{disabled: checkOnline}" >
         <v-icon>file_download</v-icon>
       </v-btn>
     </v-flex>
```

b.vue

```
import {bus} from '../main';
  const EVENTS = ['online', 'offline', 'load'];

  export default {
    props: {
      onlineClass: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      },
      offlineClass: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        isOnline: navigator.onLine,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      EVENTS.forEach(event => window.addEventListener(event, this.updateOnlineStatus));
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      EVENTS.forEach(event => window.removeEventListener(event, this.updateOnlineStatus));
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
      updateOnlineStatus() {
        this.isOnline = navigator.onLine || false;
       bus.$emit('detected-condition', this.isOnline);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is `b.vue` the mixin?

Comment: No. From **B.vue** i am emitting the function and listenting it in **x.js**. and i want it to be available for all component(like **a.vue**). I am able to get value but when i switch between component like **c.vue** and go offline in there and come back to **B.vue** it is still enable while it should change there. The reason is **a.vue** is not getting updated value.

Comment: @RitwikKumar, any progress on this issue. I'm have a similar problem.

Comment: yes, I got the solution.Not use navigator.OnLine. Use below:-

Create store and use below in mutation:-
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let file = 'https://www.telmore.dk/';
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    xhr.open('GET', file + '?rand=' + randomNum, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', checkConnection, false);

and in component:

computed: {
      getOnlineStatus() {
        return this.$store.getters.getCurrentstatus
}
 you will get exact offline/Online value. Please let me know if any issue